# Background image not working in application layout, but working in other pages

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, background-image, zurb-foundation

I want to put a background image in all of my pages, and when I simply add

```
<style>
html{background-image:url(/images/background.jpg);}
</style>
```

to the pages I want, it works, but when I put it either in Application Layout or in the application.css.scss, it does not work.

I'm using Ruby on Rails, Zurb-Foundation Gem.

In my application layout :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
  <title>Leqra.ma</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Uncomment to make IE8 render like IE7 -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /> -->

    <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/custom.modernizr" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<%= yield :head %>
  </head>
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
       <main role="main">
          <!-- before yield -->
        <%= yield %>
          <!-- after yield--> 
       </main>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
</body>
</html>
```

**PS** : *I deleted the scaffolds.cs.scss , I understand that foundation overrides html and the body styles. I tried to modify* `$body-bg` *in* `foundation_and_overrides.scss` , *but it did not seem to do the trick.*

**==========================================================================**

**Update #1** :

I seem to find a temporary solution, I put

```
html{
  background-image:url(/images/background.jpg);
}
```

in Scaffolds.css.scss.

But I still like to know why isn't it working when put in application.css.scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 html{background-image:url(/images/background.jpg) !important;}
```

Comment: Yes sir, it's working! . Can you explain pretty briefly what's happened?

Comment: certainly. your html tag is having some other css background rules applied to it that's why you couldn't apply your rule. using !important you can tell css to use your rule instead of the other one.

Comment: Makes sense, all I have to do know is to spot it. Thanks.